# Adding progressBar while google is loading its SignInIntent

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am using Google signIn authentication with firebase. On clicking google signIn button ,it takes some time in loading its signIn Intent.In that mean time I want to add a progressBar .But ProgressDialog is deprecated now so how i can add progress in that time lapse.

Answer (score 0):

Call this method on clicking signIn button,

```
 public void showProgressBar() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```

Call this method to hide progressbar,

```
    public void hideProgressBar() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);
    }
```

In your layout,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The app crashes whenever I click SignIn button after applying the above code.